# Rails sessions & social auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm creating an app with rails, devise & omniauth.
In my flow I want to take user data from providers like facebook & googlež
and use it in regular registration form.

To do this, I intend to store - temporarily - users access tokens & secrets
for facebook & twitter & google etc - in a rails session until user finishes registration.

Is it secure to do this? Since this is sensitive data, and storing it in rails session means
storing it in a cookie (although temporarily).

Are there caveats / ways to secure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose since Rails 4 sessions are encrypted by default, there shouldnt be any issues with storing this data temporarily in a session.